# dynamically fit the content of webpage to available viewable display without scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to a way to fit the contents of html body inside the viewable display.
Right now it dynamically resizes depends on the size of display, but it has a scroll bar and the height is too high.
I've looked at solutions for example doing

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

None of them worked.
This is the website https://www.time4salah.com

Comment: Use view lengths ***vw*** (view-width) and ***vh*** (view height) -> ex: `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Use `vh` and `vw` for your elements inside your body. Set `overflow:hidden;` and `margin:0;` in your body and html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query of each possible user screen size and use **calc()** to devide the height of your body.

Have more knowledge about **calc()** here: [A complete guide to calc() in css](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/)